# Is it possible to create a UITabBarController whose tabbar items have text labels only (no icons)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

In iOS, I want to create a `UITabBarController` for global app navigation (like the 'Phone' app and many others) whose tabbar items have text labels, but no icons.

I would therefore also like the height of the `UITaBar` to be much shorter. The `UITabBar` should only be tall enough to accommodate the text labels or Apple's minimum recommended button height (44pt).

Is there a standard way to say "this `UITabBar` has no icons, only text labels". If not, any advice on the best way to achieve this with a custom `UITabBar` subclass/replacement class?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the perfect task for a [UIToolbar with a UISegmentedControl](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7205/tabsh.png) dropped in.  It provides text-only tab behavior (though it might not have the appearance you're after...)

Answer (score 1):

1) I'm not sure if you can modify the size of the tab bar of `UITabBarController`- I don't think that displaying just text will shrink the tab bar size for that you probably need to look at other solutions.

2) If you want to modify how the items in tab bar look, you have to set them on the U`IViewController(s)` that you add to `UITabBarController`. See `tabBarItem` of `UIViewController`

3) You can initialize `UITabBaritem` with system defaults (`initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:` using `UITabBarSystemItem`) or using `initWithTitle:image:tag:`. In the latter case if image is nil it will not be displayed - so this should take care of text without an icon (I believe).

Look at tutorials regarding `UIViewController` or `ViewControllers` in general they will have discussion about `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this done in at least one app by creating icons with the desired text in each. Then just add the icons with the text as if they were the regular images.

Answer (score -5):

Have you seen this in a good iPhone application? No? What a surprise! It's not what UITabBar is designed for, so you shouldn't do it.

If you're that desparate, you'll have to create your own UITabBar-style class and corresponding controller.