# IOS UITabBarButtons Without image

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbar

How can i make a UITabBar without Images? I just want text, centered in the buttons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a UITabBarController whose tabbar items have text labels only (no icons)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855564/is-it-possible-to-create-a-uitabbarcontroller-whose-tabbar-items-have-text-label)

Comment: hummm so it's not possible :S

Comment: It wouldn't meet UI guidelines anyway - that is what a UIToolbar with a UISegmentedControl is for.

Comment: Yes, the only problem is that i already had all the structure based on the tabs, and subviews created. tks anyway :)

Comment: Then why not use images? Glyphish icons are pretty good.

Comment: The design is not my department :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "centered", you mean "horizontally-centered", I would just use fully transparent PNG images for your design.

I you also mean "vertically-centered", there's no way to achieve this with UITabBar and text.

Maybe you can trick it by using an empty text for your tab but creating images for the text you want but the text will be rendered blue and it might be ugly/not meet Apple's standards so I would strongly advise you against it.

Comment: tks, I think that i will go for a segmentedcontrol instead